# List comprehensions where entry occurs twice in a row

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, kaggle

I wrote code for an assignment on Kaggle.

"Given a list of meals served over some period of time, return True if the same meal has ever been served two days in a row, and False otherwise."

```
def menu_is_boring(meals):
    return any([ meals[l] == meals[l+1] for l in range(0,len(meals)-2) ])
```

Expected return value of True given `meals=['Spam', 'Spam']`, but got False instead.

Comment: It should be `len(meals) -1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your example, `len(meals)` is 2, so `len(meals)-2` is `0`, so the range is empty.

you only need to subtract 1.

try this:

```py
def menu_is_boring(meals):
    return any([meals[l] == meals[l + 1] for l in range(0, len(meals) - 1)])


print(menu_is_boring(["Spam", "Spam"]))
```

Output:

> True

it's worth noting that python's `range` is not inclusive of the `stop` param (i.e., `list(range(1,5))` is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`)

Answer (score 3):

When you are to compare two successive values over a range, you could use `zip` to create the pairs and iterate over the pairs and compare:

```
any(i == j for i, j in zip(meals, meals[1:]))
```

Here I've used generator expression, but you're free to use list comprehension if you want.

Another option would be to use `itertools.tee` to create two iterators, consume the first element from second iterator and then iterate over pairs:

```
def menu_is_boring(meals): 
    it_1, it_2 = itertools.tee(meals) 
    next(it_2) 
    return any(i == j for i, j in zip(it_1, it_2))
```

This would be slower than the first one.

So for example:

```
In [1104]: def menu_is_boring(meals): 
      ...:     return any(i == j for i, j in zip(meals, meals[1:])) 
      ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [1105]: meals=['Spam', 'Spam']   

In [1106]: menu_is_boring(meals)                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[1106]: True

In [1107]: def menu_is_boring(meals): 
      ...:     it_1, it_2 = itertools.tee(meals) 
      ...:     next(it_2) 
      ...:     return any(i == j for i, j in zip(it_1, it_2)) 
      ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [1108]: menu_is_boring(meals)                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[1108]: True
```

Comment: It's better to use a generator expression than a list comp with `any` or `all`. Both those functions short-circuit, that is, they bail out as soon as the result is certain. So `any` stops testing as soon as it finds a True result. So if you feed it a generator, the generator stops when `any` bails out. But if you feed `any` a list comp, the whole list has to be created before `any` can start work.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def menu_is_boring(meals):
    counter=0
    
    for i in range(0, len(meals) - 1):
        if meals[i]==meals[i+1]:
            counter=counter+1
            
    if counter!=0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
def menu_is_boring(meals):
    """Given a list of meals served over some period of time, return True if the
    same meal has ever been served two days in a row, and False otherwise.
    """
    
    for i in range(len(meals)):
         for j in range(len(meals)-(i+1)):            
            #print(meals[i])
            #print(meals[j+(i+1)])
            if meals[i] == meals[j+(i+1)]:               
                return True                
    return False
           
meals= ["water","pear","apple","egg", "orange","apple"]

menu_is_boring(meals)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.